# Angular material UI display tab content in a row

Tags: angular, sass, flexbox, tabs, angular-material

I am trying to style Material Ui tabs. I arranged my code to generically display tabs and within each tab, you have 3 main categories with items that belong to the category. As you can see below this was the design I had in mind.

[image: What it should look like]

This is how it looks like in my code. So dev Ops should be the column title and 2 cards below it are items that belong to it but then instead of showing the next column next to it is way below it.

[image: What it looks like in my project]

This is my code. Could anyone explain to me how I get the column next to each other I tried to play with flex-direction row and column but no luck
Html :

```
 <mat-tab-group>
                <mat-tab *ngFor="let test$ of testArr;" [label]="test$.category">
                    <ng-template matTabContent>
                            <div class="skills-column" *ngFor="let skillcolumn of test$.subtest">
                                <div>
                                    <h3>{{skillcolumn.subcat}}</h3>
                                    <mat-card class="skill-name" *ngFor="let skillcard of skillcolumn.items">
                                        <mat-card-title>{{skillcard.skill}}</mat-card-title>
                                    </mat-card>
                                </div>
                                <mat-divider [vertical]="true"></mat-divider>
                            </div>
                    </ng-template>
                </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
```

sccs

```
 .mat-tab-group {
                    margin-top: 2%;
                    margin-left: 5%;
                    width: 85%;
                    height: 100%;


                        .skills-column {
                            margin-top: 5%;
                            width:100%;
                            height:100%;
                            display: flex;
                            flex-direction: row;


                            .div {
                                width:50%;


                                .skill-name {
                                    width: 95px;
                                    height: 95px;
                                }
                            }
                        
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. I needed to add an extra outer div around skills-column with display flex row and also I somehow typed div as a class! I can't believe I didn't notice this sooner!

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let test$ of testArr;" [label]="test$.category">
        <ng-template matTabContent >
            <div>
                <div class="skills-column" *ngFor="let skillcolumn of test$.subtest">
                    <div>
                        <h3>{{skillcolumn.subcat}}</h3>
                        <mat-card class="skill-name" *ngFor="let skillcard of skillcolumn.items">
                            <mat-card-title>{{skillcard.skill}}</mat-card-title>
                        </mat-card>
                    </div>
                    <mat-divider [vertical]="true"></mat-divider>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

SCSS:

```
 .mat-tab-group {
                margin-top: 2%;
                margin-left: 5%;
                width: 85%;
                height: 100%;


                 div{
                     display: flex;
                     flex-direction: row;
                    .skills-column {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: row;

                        div {
                           
                            display: flex;
                            flex-direction: column;


                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: In my case I was putting cards outof <ng-template matTabContent></ng-template>, seeing your example I got the correct way to put cards inside.